# Using a gem in Ruby on Rails does not seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed the [`gem ruby-imagespec`](https://github.com/andersonbrandon/ruby-imagespec)

The code looks like the following:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def ratio(fid)
    file = File.new("#{Rails.public_path}/test/#{fid}.swf", "rb")
    dimensions = ImageSpec.new(file)
    return dimensions
  end
  helper_method :ratio
end
```

When I try to run this I get an error:

> "uninitialized constant TestController::ImageSpec" on line 7   The
>   gem is listed in the gemfile and explicitly requiring it does not
>   work.

Where is the error? The gem is installed correctly and this code is just like the code from the gem's README

Comment: have your run `bundle install`?

Comment: of course i did, i even had the gem installed before and (just to make sure) tried to install it again after the error occured (which was successful). That did not fix the issue though.

Comment: try giving this statement before the controller `require 'ruby-imagespec'`

Comment: Also, try storing some swf image in your file system, give that path using `instance = ImageSpec.new('/path/to/your/file')` and see if that works, if that works, there is some error in the IO stream for sure.

Comment: @Inquisitive is probably right. Most gems must explicitly required - it saves a lot of memory. Its usually only rails specific gems that inject themselves into your app

Comment: I tried it with the "require 'ruby-imagespec'", didn't change anything and as you can see the swf IS stored on my file system already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the ruby-imagespec repository](https://github.com/andersonbrandon/ruby-imagespec), the file you need to require appears to be lib/image_spec.rb. Try `require 'image_spec'`.

Answer (score 0):

ruby-imagespec is an unsupported gem, please try fastimage:

add `gem 'fastimage'` in your Gemfile

here the documentation https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage

Comment: fastimage does not seem to support swf (adobe flash) files because it's stated nowhere and returns nil if i use it on one